# How do I turn off reply updates in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I tried to click "Turn off Reply Updates", but it doesn't work and I continue to get reply notifications. I miss the old style of notifications where you click it and it shows the video in the notification popup. Now it takes you to a new page and there is no way to turn off notifications even if you tell it to. I'm using Chrome.

[image: youtube notifications]

Comment: Really interested in getting this sorted. Kinda nightmarish to keep receiving notifications for a shouting match thread you tried to be constructive on... ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on https://www.youtube.com/account_notifications, the checkboxes under *Comments & Activity* are responsible for whether you get notifications for comments on your videos and comments you've replied to, respectively.

Comment: Hmm, "Activity on my comments on others' videos" is already turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but it's absolutely infuriating, the best and only thing I've found you can do is to open up a new tab, or Google, and hope that the notification is in the bell on the top right since that still acts like the old version, with proper +person replies and ability to mute, though whether it shows up is ~50-50.

Generally if you see a '1' on YouTube, open up Google and see if it's there too before opening it.

Comment: Oh, that doesn't work for me, because I use a different name on YouTube than in Google, so I have no previous notifications in Google+ or Google.com like I do in YouTube.

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer on the [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/xj6uAu2ISaE).

You should be able to "mute" the conversation so you don't get reply notifications.

> You can do that as follows:
>
> 1. Wait for a notification for a reply in that conversation to appear under the bell icon
> 2. Click the notification so the post shows, still under the bell icon
> 3. In the upper right corner of the post, click the little down arrow
> 4. Select the "mute post" option   Note that the option to mute the discussion is usually an option on the original comment post itself,
>      but there seems to be a current glitch that's made that option
>      disappear except for under the notification bell.
>
> Note that the option to mute the discussion is usually an option on the original comment post itself, but there seems to be a current glitch that's made that option disappear except for under the notification bell.
>
> [image: screen shot]

Comment: That's a screen shot from the old notification system. My screen shot is from the new notification system, which doesn't have the option to 'mute post'.